# Accessing the last element in the list in python

Tags: python, string, list

Actually i had a list for example

```
list_1 = ["hi","hello","nice"]
```

**1.** Now i need to access only last element of the list, and the elements in the list are not fixed , i mean the length of the list will be increased(there is a chance to add more strings), whatever the elements in the list i need to access only last element of the list.
If it is a string we can do it by `slicing`, but how to do this with a list
**2.** I want to remove only the last element in the list irrespective of length of the list as above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about reading the tutorial? http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access last elemet

```
>>> myl = [1,2,3]
>>> myl[-1]
3
```

And to remove take look at

[list.pop([i])](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If
>   no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in
>   the list.

Comment: Actually my intension is to select only starting two elements from the list, thats what i want to do, if we do pop last element is removed and returned.

Comment: Two select only first two element do `myl[0:2]`. Read more on `list slicing`.